# C, turning camel text into snake text

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am total beginner, I want to make an application that for each lower *camel case* word supplied as a command line argument will print it's *snake case* equivalent. Also turns big letters into smaller ones and makes between them `"_"`.

**Example:**

```
./coverter Iwant tobe famousAlready.
```

**output:**

```
i_want
tobe
famous_already
```

I have found some code to make the letters smaller, and output words in the command line separately. But I have no clue how to put them together, how to appeal into single character in function main? Is this even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]);
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}

char change()
{
    char words[30]; 
    int ch;

    printf ("Give the words: ");

    int i=0;

    while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        slowko[i]=ch;
        if(isupper(slowko[i])) /* isupper, robi rzeczy - sprawdza czy */
                               /* litera z sekwencji jest duza */
        {
            slowko[i]=tolower(ch); /*zamien duzy znak na maly*/
            printf("_");
        }
        else if(slowko[i] == ' ')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf ("%c", slowko[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use two input-methods here: argument vectors, and interactive streams with `getchar`. Based on the problem statement, one should not use streams, but have a string argument to your function.

Comment: Your first test case doesn't match the usual definition. Usually, the only place where an underscore is inserted is between a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You have command line arguments inside `argv` array starting from  index 1. Maybe, it's not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_snake_case(const char str[]){

    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(isupper((unsigned char) str[i])) /*isupper, robi rzeczy - sprawdza     czy     litera z sekwencji jest duza*/
        {
            const char ch = tolower((unsigned char) str[i]); /*zamien duzy znak na maly*/

            /*
               Different order of "_": it should be placed after
               the character in case it's at the beginning of the word.         
               And before the character if it's not at the beginning.
            */
            if(i != 0)
            {
                printf("_");
                printf ("%c", ch);
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("%c", ch);
                printf("_");
            }
        }
        else
            printf ("%c", str[i]);


        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        print_snake_case(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./converter Iwant tobe famousAlready
i_want
tobe
famous_already
```

Comment: Why `char change`? And why isn't its parameter a `const char *`? The function should better be called `print_snake_case` instead of `change` since the latter name is way too unspecific. Plus, you invoke undefined behavior when passing a possibly signed `char` to `tolower`.

Comment: @RolandIllig "Why char change?" - replaced to void

Comment: @RolandIllig "why isn't its parameter a const char *?" - it was modified inside a function. But const is better. Fixed.

Comment: @RolandIllig "The function should better be called print_snake_case instead of change" - fixed

Comment: @RolandIllig "you invoke undefined behavior when passing a possibly signed char to tolower" - is there anything we can do about it?

Comment: Yes, cast the char to `unsigned char`, in both `isupper` and `tolower`. See [the NetBSD man page](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ctype+3+NetBSD-current) for a brief explanation.

Comment: @RolandIllig Done. Should `ch` be `const char` or `const unsigned char`?

Comment: it doesn't matter if `ch` is `int` or `unsigned char` or `char`. The result will be the same. Since `tolower` returns an `int` and the `%c` conversion requires an `int` as well, this is the most natural choice, even though it does not carry the additional information that `ch` is a character. That must be inferred from the context. The `const` is not necessary though.